# Bootstrap select not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have something like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="level">
<option value="Field">Field admin</option>
<option value="Text">Text admin</option>
<option value="Bot">Bot</option>
</select>
```

With this at the bottom:

```
<script src='./clientLib/bootstrap-select.js'></script>
```

Adding this (at the bottom of the page after loading the above script) doesn't work:

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Right now, the button gets formatted but clicking the select does not load the drop down. Pressing alt loads the drop down but there is no way to close the dropdown, even if I select an option.

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the script in the head section of the page and this '$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();' at the bottom of the page

Comment: I tried this and it is still the same unfortunately

Comment: What errors do you see when you open the google chrome inspector?

Comment: No errors at all. I can scroll down by pressing alt but that is about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure will be

```
    <head>
    <!-- Stylesheet for Bootstrap Core CSS-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Stylesheet for Bootstrap Select-picker-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
          <select class="selectpicker" name="level">
               <option value="Field">Field admin</option>
               <option value="Text">Text admin</option>
               <option value="Bot">Bot</option>
          </select>

         <!-- JS for Core jQuery v1.11.3-->
         <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- JS for Core Bootstrap-->
         <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
         <!-- JS for Bootstrap Select-picker-->
         <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

You can use this script under all js:-

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

If you face any error, you can use:-

```
 jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the bootstrap-select.js after the default bootstrap and jquery scripts in the footer- that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u put this on the top of page u want to use bootstrap Select

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
</script>
```

and Check the path of Files to be sure its correct.
its should work.

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="level">
  <option value="Field">Field admin</option>
  <option value="Text">Text admin</option>
  <option value="Bot">Bot</option>
</select>
```

Best Regards
Kianoor

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue

Fixed by calling bootstrap js

Before the button Select js